# Sql count inside groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table/view:

```
Department    number_of_customers    number_of_employess  

dep1           10                   15  
dep3           20                   18  
dep1           11                   11  
dep2           6                    8  
dep2           20                   1
```

I would like to group by department and then for each grouped record counting the rows having certain properties
for example number_of_customer > number_of_employees

My current query looks like this:

```
  SELECT dep,count(*)  
    FROM My_table  
   WHERE n_of_cust > n_of_employees  
GROUP BY dep
```

but that's not what I want because
for example dep1 doesn't appear in the result table
and I would like it to be present.

PS: please someone help me with the indentation of the table.

Comment: In the WHERE clause you have "n_of_cust > n_of_employees", which means no dep1 rows will be included. Then you say you want dep1 to be included. You have to decide if dep1 should be there or not! What are you trying to count btw? Why are dep1 and dep2 mentioned twice in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression like `number_of_customers > number_of_employees` has a value of either `1` (true) or `0` (false). You can apply `SUM()` to such expressions in a `GROUP BY` query.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT dep,
       count(*) totalrows,
       SUM(n_of_cust > n_of_employees) many_cust_rows,
       SUM(n_of_cust = n_of_employees) equal_cust_rows
  FROM My_table
  GROUP BY dep
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `JOIN` with the same table. Something like:

```
     SELECT t1.dep, s1.quantity
       FROM My_table AS t1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT dep,count(*)
               FROM My_table
              WHERE n_of_cust > n_of_employees
           GROUP BY dep
            ) AS s1 ON t1.dep = d1.dep
```